# Couldn't Find Template Iron Router

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

I'm struggling with a very basic implementation of Iron Router for my Meteor JS app, even after looking through SO answers. I am unable to get the layout template recognized, the error when I go to localhost:3000 is - "Cannot find template named 'layout' are you sure you defined it?"

What I have:

Router.js

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
Router.map(function(){
  this.route('feed', {path: '/'});
  this.route('login', {path: '/login'});
  this.route('profile', {path: '/profile'});
});
```

layout.html (within client folder)

```
<template name="layout">
  {{> yield}}
  {{> navbar}}
</template>
```

navbar.html (within client folder)

```
<template name="navbar">
  <div id="footer-nav" class="text-center">
    <input class="text-center" type="file" id="exampleInput">
  </div>
</template>
```

Seems like a bug, thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Go to the console on the client and type `typeof(Template.layout)` and see what comes back. It should be `object`.

Comment: No luck. ReferenceError: Template is not defined

Comment: That means this is not a router issue but for some reason your layout template is not being seen by meteor. Check spelling and file location of your definition of `<template name="layout">`

Comment: Is there any more code in layout.html? Or any compile time warnings on the server side console?

Comment: I was trying to use meteoric:ionic and it was making the templates unrecognizable - removing it fixed the issue. Not sure why this package doesn't work.

Comment: Same issue faced by me. Any result ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue for a month now, and I just, now, found the answer at this following link. I hope it helps out:

https://mplatts.gitbooks.io/learn-meteor-js/content/1/routing/layout.html

Apparently, according to the material discussed in the provided link above, it is a problem of **reorganising the folders** and having the **"route match the template"**.

- Your client/main.html or client/index.html file needs a **title** in the
  head tags.

```html
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
```

- then your layout template, in the client/views folder, needs to reference the same **title** like:

```html
<template name = 'layout'>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  {{> yield}}
  {{> navbar}}
</template>
```

- Last but not least, your router.js file needs to be in a both folder, to be accessible by the client and the server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).